# Unable to get contacts,SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient() throwing an exception

Tags: sitecore-client, xdb, xconnect, contact-facets, custom-facet

I'm trying to get the contacts but while creating an instance of xconnect client, I'm getting the following exception:

> Type must have a parameterless constructor (not necessarily public) or a public constructor that only takes parameters that correspond to primitive types

Here is the pseudo code for reference.

```
using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
          List<Contact> contacts = null;
          contact = client.Get<Contact>(new IdentifiedContactReference(AssemblyFacetInformation.ContactReference, "bcc746fa19cd6fddf0203aa443eebd11"), new ContactExecutionOptions(new ContactExpandOptions(AssemblyFacetInformation.ContactReference)));
          var contact = contacts.FirstOrDefault();
          var assemblyFacetInformation = contact.GetFacet<AssemblyFacetInformation>(AssemblyFacetInformation.Timezone);
          assemblyFacetInformation.TimeZone = windowsTimeZone;
          client.SetFacet(contact, AssemblyFacetInformation.Timezone, assemblyFacetInformation);
          client.Submit();

        }
```

My Custom model class

```
public class AssemblyFacetCollectionModel
  {
    public static XdbModel Model { get; } = BuildAssemblyModel();
    static XdbModel BuildAssemblyModel()
    {
      XdbModelBuilder xdbModelBuilder = new XdbModelBuilder("AssemblyFacetInformation", new XdbModelVersion(1, 0));
      xdbModelBuilder.ReferenceModel(CollectionModel.Model);
      xdbModelBuilder.DefineFacet<Contact, AssemblyFacetInformation>(AssemblyFacetInformation.DefaultFacetKey);
      return xdbModelBuilder.BuildModel();
    }
  }
```

This is my facet class

```
[FacetKey(DefaultFacetKey)]
  [Serializable]
  public class AssemblyFacetInformation : Facet
  {
    public const string IdentifierCookieName = "_assembly_visitor_id";
    public const string AnalyticsCookieName = "analytics_uuid";
    public const string MetroCookieName = "metro";
    public const string ContactReference = "Assembly_Visitor";
    public const string DefaultFacetKey = "AssemblyFacetKey";
    public const string Timezone = "Timezone";
    public AssemblyFacetInformation() { }

    [JsonProperty("metro")]
    public Metro metro { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("geolocated_location")] //From "metro" Cookie
    public string GeoLocation { get; set; } //From "metro" Cookie
    [JsonProperty("distance_from_metro")]
    public float DistanceFromMetro { get; set; } //From "metro" Cookie
    [JsonProperty("latitude")]
    public float UserLatitude { get; set; } //From "metro" Cookie
    [JsonProperty("longitude")]
    public float UserLongitude { get; set; } //From "metro" Cookie
    [JsonProperty("prioritize_online")]
    public bool PrioritizeOnline { get; set; } //From "metro" Cookie
    //[JsonProperty("metro")]
    //public string ShopSession { get; set; } //From "_shop_session" Cookie
    [JsonProperty("time_zone")]
    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone { get; set; }

  }
```

While debugging the process I found that exception originally thrown by the AssemblyFacetCollectionModel class on this line

```
      return xdbModelBuilder.BuildModel();
```

Did I miss something or doing anything wrong??

Comment: Try commenting out `Metro` and `TimeZone`  fields temporarily. I think they are the reason of your issues.

Comment: You were right @MarekMusielak these two fields were creating an issue. But now I'm getting this error. `One or more local models conflict with the xDB service layer.
 'AssemblyFacetKey, 1.0' does not have a remote version'`

Comment: You should not mix multiple questions in one post. Create new question describing the whole situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with `Metro` and `TimeZoneInfo` types.

Either remove them or make sure that they are registered properly in your model and have proper constructors.

Read more about type restrictions here:

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/the-xconnect-model.html